# Retrieving null data when using promise in express

Tags: node.js, express, monk

so I have a project where I'm accessing a db table either by ID or name.

My category route:

```
 router.get('/name/:name', function(req, res) {
   Category.fetchName(res, req.params.name);
   console.log(res.name);

 });
```

My category model:

```
static fetchName(res, categoryName) {
  categories.find({
      name: categoryName
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      res.send(doc);
      console.log(doc);

    });
}
```

When I do the `console.log(doc)` it's printing out the array

`[ { _id: 57f7d8382604126103f0113b, name: 'stuff' } ]`

But when I access it in my route it says `undefined`. What am I missing? Why can't I access the data fetched from the db in my route?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will not get `res.name` since you are not adding anywhere `name property` in `res` object.

```
router.get('/name/:name', function(req, res) {
  Category.fetchName(res, req.params.name, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(result);
       res.send(result);
    }
  });
});


static fetchName(res, categoryName,callback) {
  categories.find({
      name: categoryName
    })
    .then((doc) => {
      callback(null,doc);
      console.log(doc);
    });
}
```

Comment: still can't access res.name in my routes, it still says "undefined" while I got the correct console.log result when doing it my model...

Comment: if I did a console.log in my routes after I called the async method in model, I would expect it's coming back after it retrieved the data from the db, so the name should be there or am I missing something?

Comment: are you getting the proper value in result?

Comment: you should get all the information in result parameter